# How to automatically build test modules with stack?

Tags: haskell, testing, haskell-stack

I have this `Spec.hs`:

```
    import qualified OtherSpec

    main :: IO ()
    main = do
        putStrLn "Test..."
        OtherSpec.main
```

And I am planning to add more test suites from other modules to its `main`.

When I run tests as:

```
$ stack test --file-watch
```

A few things happen:

- Tests are re-run when `OtherSpec.hs` is changed, but the test executable is not rebuilt.
- When I change `Spec.hs` test executable is rebuilt and changes in `OtherSpec.hs` is also picked.

Is there a way to trigger a rebuild when `OtherSpec.hs` changes?

---

I am using stack version 0.1.2.0.

Comment: an immediate fix would be to add --force-dirty - see https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/tag/v0.1.3.0

Comment: which version of stack are you using?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I have added the stack version. This is from Debian package repository (stretch).

Comment: I tried to `stack upgrade` but it ends up in kernel panic. *Experimental* indeed.

Comment: what about apt-get upgrade?? - if you are using the deb-repository

Comment: That's the current version. Packages take some time to get into the repositories unless packagers are devs/users of the project.

Comment: I'd recommend following the installation guide here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/install_and_upgrade.md